# Появление div при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Итак. Имеется такой блок див с идентификатором и свойством. Внутри есть инфа, которую нужно скрыть и показать по мигалке (по нажатию на ссылку):

```
<div id="methodCaesar" style="display:none">
```

Имеется такая ссылка:

```
<a id="Caesar" href="" onclick="show('methodCaesar')">Шифр цезаря</a>
```

И имеется код JS:

```
function show(id)
{
    var div = document.getElementById(id)
    if(div.style.display == '') 
        div.style.display = 'none'
    else 
        div.style.display = ''
}
```

Спрашивается: какого черта не работает?
Причем не работает странно. Загружаю страницу, нажимаю на кнопку, и, если алерт поставить в начало скрипта, то метод легко выведет информацию о передаваемому по параметру методу.
Затем, блок див с идентификатором methodCaesar появится. А затем исчезнет вновь!
Если зайти в инспектор кода, то там видно, что ДОМ обновляется 2 раза (но алерт выведется лишь 1 раз, то есть всё же скрипт выполняется 1 раз).
К тому же, если писать в консоли show("methodCaesar"), то всё прекрасно работает как и задумано.
Пользуюсь браузером Хром. И хочу, чтобы работало на хром...
Чёрт знает что, полностью голову сломал, подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить # в href="#"

```
<a id="Caesar" href="#" onclick="show('methodCaesar')">Шифр цезаря</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Заработало, конечно.
А так он, видимо, просто-напросто перезагружал текущую страницу?

Answer (score 0):

Ничего необычного! При переходе по ссылке страница обновляется и результат исчезает. Попробуй использовать вместо ссылки  другой текстовый элемент.